# JBoss 6.4 - Oracle database connection lost

Tags: oracle, java-8, jboss

We have an app running on Jboss 6.4 and had no issues in the past few months.

But suddenly,

The datasource active connections got destroyed in the active pool, with an error message below:

```
(org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool:758) : IJ000615: Destroying active connection in pool: VIPR_Datasource (org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@16837cf)
```

At the same time, we got bunch of calls that failed due to no active connections, and the below message

```
 (org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources:145) : JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
```

The application has a database reconnect code, that reconnects to the database and we had minimal damage, but trying to understand how can an active connection get destroyed in Production.

Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was affected by the liveness probe, the database connection was lost automatically because the application running on Jboss restarted itself since the timeout on the liveness probe was very less.

After increasing the timeout, the issue was resolved.